# CMake DragNDrop framework rpath for qt not set when targeting package

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, qt5, rpath

When creating a DragNDrop bundle of my project using the qt framework provided by brew qt5.13.0 the rpath does not seem to be honored although I am setting it to the path I copy the Framework to in my bundle.

I have tried `set(MACOSX_RPATH ON)` and `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)` but the results remained using a static path instead of rpath and failing to find the bundled Framework on other machines brew qt 5.13.0

in 5.9.5 all that was needed for my cmake to work as expected was
`set (CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@executable_path/../Frameworks")`
and further down for packaging

```
        set (CPACK_GENERATOR "DragNDrop")
        install (DIRECTORY ${Qt5_DIR}/../../QtCore.framework DESTINATION *.app/Contents/Frameworks)
        install (DIRECTORY ${Qt5_DIR}/../../QtGui.framework DESTINATION *.app/Contents/Frameworks)
        install (DIRECTORY ${Qt5_DIR}/../../QtPrintSupport.framework DESTINATION *.app/Contents/Frameworks)
        install (DIRECTORY ${Qt5_DIR}/../../QtTest.framework DESTINATION *.app/Contents/Frameworks)
        install (DIRECTORY ${Qt5_DIR}/../../QtWidgets.framework DESTINATION *.app/Contents/Frameworks)
        install (FILES "${Qt5_DIR}/../../../plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib" DESTINATION *.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms)
```

On qt 5.9.5 from the opensource installer I see the following results with otool -L

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1570.15.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.5)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.5)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.9.0, current version 5.9.5)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

whereas when using qt 5.13.0 from brew I get the following

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1575.17.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    /usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I finally figured out what was going on. 
as seen [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/qt.rb#L39) when brew builds qt they use the `-no-rpath` option. So rather than go through and use install_name_tool on the frameworks I needed I discovered a neat trick about the qt-online-installer. It was script-able and I found a repo with that in it, see [qtci](https://github.com/benlau/qtci.git) by benlau.

Then after adding

```
        - git clone https://github.com/benlau/qtci.git; 
        - source qtci/path.env; 
        - install-qt-online qt.qt5.5130.clang_64 ~/
```

to the -travis.yml I could set my `Qt_DIR="~/qt/5.13.0/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5"` and link with the expected rpaths

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1575.17.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.13.0, current version 5.13.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.4)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.250.1)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```